# WebScript VBA array especifica

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, web-scraping

tudo bem?

Estou fazendo um web scraping pra atualizar uma planilha minha no vba. Porém o site que quero puxar essas informações usam td e tr e não colocam class ou id nas sintaxe.

Por exemplo:

estou usando: ie.document.getelementsbytagname ("tr") (0).innertext

Sendo que que tenho que ficar adivinhando o array do tag nome até chegar onde eu quero, e outras páginas o array pode ser diferente.

Uma constante que sempre se repete é o conteudo do produto que eu quero pegar. É sempre o mesmo.

Existe alguma forma de especificar pra ele pegar o TR caso tenha a minha constante?

Por exemlo: ie.document.getelementsbytagname ("tr") (caso tenha a constante 1).innertext.

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando o selenium?

Mas basicamente, você pode pegar todos os elementos 'tr' e depois, realizar um loop procurando seu valor.

Se possível poste seu código, fica mais fácil para passar uma resposta mais específica.